# Commit not showing up in history

Tags: git, git-rebase

I made a mistake and now my commit is not showing up in the history. I had a remote branch checked out in read only mode (without <s>actually switching to that branch</s> creating a local branch). I made 3 commits, without checking out master again.

I want to rebase those commits to master, but they are not showing up in the history. How can I do it?

Comment: How do you check out a remote branch, read-only without switching to it.  Don't get that bit. Please post the commands as best you can.

Comment: I am sorry, I actually meant without creating a local branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this was done recently (30 days or so) the commits should still be in `git reflog` which will show a list of all commits that were the `HEAD` recently.  Then you can `git merge` or `git cherry-pick` the SHA id(s) of the commits into your master branch.

If this was not done recently it's possible the commits were removed by `git gc` but you can run `git fsck` and examine any `dangling commits` listed.  One of them may be your lost commit.